# View Expanded Search Paths in XCode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any plugin or trick to easily view **resolved**  search paths or other parameters in XCode build settings ?

For example I have
[image]

I can see the first item of the resolved path, and then have to re-order them to see more

[image]